# ExtJS Ajax problems for grid panel

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have a grid Panel in my code as:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        id : 'frPanel-' + interfaceId,
        store : frStore,
        columns : [
                {
                    text : 'Sequence',
                    dataIndex : 'ruleId',
                    menuDisabled : true
                },
                {
                    text : 'Source',
                    dataIndex : 'source',
                    renderer : function(value, metaData) {
                        var newValue = convertObjValue(value);
                        if (newValue.match(/[-]+/i)) {
                            metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="'
                                    + networkStore(value) + '"';
                        }
                        return newValue;
                    }
                },
// paging bar at the bottom
        dockedItems : [ {
            xtype : 'pagingtoolbar',
            store : frStore, // same store GridPanel is using
            dock : 'bottom',
            displayInfo : true
        } ],
height : 300,
        width : '100%',
        forceFit : true,
        renderTo : 'frContainer-' + interfaceId
    });
```

And these are the helper function i have:

```
// To get the value after 2nd colon for object and object-group
function convertObjValue(value) {
    var result;
    var exp = /.*?:.*?:(.*)/i;
    var newValue = value;

    if ((result = exp.exec(value)) != null) {
        if (result.index === exp.lastIndex) {
            exp.lastIndex++;
        }
        newValue = result[1];
    }
    return newValue;
}
```

The store:

```
function networkStore(value) {

//var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
    model : 'networkModel',
    autoLoad : {
        timeout : 60000
    },
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : networkObjsURL + "&" + Ext.urlEncode({
            'peId' : value
        }),
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            idProperty : 'objValue'
        },
     }
});
var hoverOutput = "";

if(store.data.length > 0){
store.data.items.forEach(function(item) {
    hoverOutput += item.data.objectValue + "</br>";
});
}
console.log(hoverOutput);
return hoverOutput;
```

and last but not the least is the model:

```
Ext.define('networkModel', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [ {
        name : 'objectValue'
    } ]
});
```

Now comes the issue. The problem is when i dont place the breakpoint in the browser in store, the values wont show up in qtip. Im guessing thats because of the grid panel not waiting for the response back from the store after ajax response. Can someone help me figure out a workaround for this situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Common guys need a little help here!

Comment: Anyone else want to give this a shot? Im kinda stuck on this issue for some time now.

Comment: Please create a fiddle for this issue

Comment: You should try to cut your code to the bone to get just the minimum required to reproduce the issue. Nobody wants to wade through some random code from your application unrelated to the problem at hand.

Comment: Which version ExtJS? 5? Control Flow in your code is strange for me. Why do you create store in `render` function indirectly (directly in `networkStore`) (multiple times)? 
Nevertheless, store is fetching data async. so you have to wait/callback result (or use Future/Promise API for example).
In addition, you should have any necessary data for the grid in `frStore` store (which you pass to the grid). You can take advantage of data association in your model, so you can create new field in model or just use that association in `render` function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting

```
autoLoad:false
```

and then something like :

```
store.load({
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        if (success == true) {
            //do your stuff
            var hoverOutput = "";

            if(store.data.length > 0){
            store.data.items.forEach(function(item) {
                hoverOutput += item.data.objectValue + "</br>";
            });
            }
            console.log(hoverOutput);
            return hoverOutput;
        } else {
            // the store didn't load, deal with it
        }
    }
    // scope: this,
});
```

Since your breakpoint allows you to see your data, im thinking you are right in assuming it's a delay issue. Since Ext is asynchronous, it wont wait for the ajax call to be finished before continuing it's processing. A callback will help you manage this as it will be called  when ajax returns. 
I'm still also fairly new to Ext but at least that's my understanding. Hope it helps, or at least points you in the right way.

Edit because i reminded that sometimes having a return inside the success will make it hard to debug, etc. So you could also try changing your success to call another function and have that function do the processing, just keep the scope in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I asked in comment which version ExtJS you're using but I didn't get response so I assume that you are using ExtJS 5.

Control Flow in your code is strange for me.
Why do you create store in `render` function indirectly (directly in `networkStore`) multiple times?

Nevertheless, store is fetching data asynchronous, so you have to wait/callback result (or use Future/Promise API for example). In addition, you should have any necessary data for the grid in `frStore` store (which you pass to the grid). You can also take advantage of data association in your model or you can create new field in model with `convert` function and use value of the association/field in `render` function.

Let me show you one of the approach how to do that (a simple one).

ExtJS doesn't like modifying records inside render function so we prepare a model which has a necessary `qtip` value.

I assume that you can load data of `networkStore` earlier (autoload: true) but this is for simplicity and you can change it later, for example using `remoteFilter` and callbacks.

You don't show definition of `frStore` and underlying model so I will use `FrStore` and `FrModel` as class names.

```
Ext.define('FrModel', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  // ...
  fields: [
    // source field
    // ...
    /** qtip value **/
    {
      name: 'qtip',
      type: 'string',
      convert: function (value, record) {
        var result = '';
        // below code is from your render function with modifications
        if (record.get('rendered_source').match(/[-]+/i)) {
          result = 'data-qtip="'
             + networkStore(record.get('source')) + '"';
        }
        return result;
      },
      depends: ['source', 'rendered_source']
    },
    /** rendered source **/
    {
      name: 'rendered_source',
      type: 'string',
      convert: function (value, record) {
        var newValue = convertObjValue(record.get('source'));
        return newValue;
      },
      depends: ['source']
    }
  ]
  // ...
}
```

After that change `render` function is simple:

```
// ...
{
  text : 'Source',
  dataIndex : 'rendered_source', // this will allow users to sort & filter this field by the values which are displayed
  renderer : function(value, metaData, record) {
      metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="'
        + record.get('qtip') + '"';
    }
    return value;
  }
},
// ...
```

You can need also a `NetworkStore` which you could place in seperate file: (I prefer proxy/schema in model but I've used your code)

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { // using Ext.create is better
    model : 'networkModel',
    storeId: 'networkStore', // registering store in  Ext.data.StoreManager in order to get later this store by Ext.getStore(<store_id>)
    autoLoad : true,
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : networkObjsURL, // we load all records but I mentioned earlier that you can change this
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            idProperty : 'objValue'
        },
     }
});
```

I added `peId` field in `netowrkModel` because we want to query store later.

```
Ext.define('networkModel', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [
      {
        name: 'objectValue'
      },
      {
        name: 'peId',
        type: 'int'
      }
    ]
});
```

The last part is the `networkStore` function:

```
function networkStore(value) {
  var store = Ext.getStore('networkStore');
  var records = store.query('peId', value, false, true, true);
  var hoverOutput = "";

  if (records.length > 0) {
    records.each(function(item) {
      hoverOutput += item.get('objectValue') + "</br>";
    });
  }

  console.log(hoverOutput);
  return hoverOutput;
}
```

PS. I do not test above code.

However, IMO correct solution uses associations. I recommend you read [this doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/core_concepts/data_package.html).

You should get to know concepts like schema, proxy, association and others.

When you join `FrModel` with `NetworkModel` by `peId` then you won't need `NetworkStore` and you build `qtip` in `convert` function based on that association.

Comment: im using 4.2.1 @rzymek